# JavaScript not able to specify font and focus for newly appending element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add new element to an exiting element on some mouse event. I am able to append it but I am not able to specify font-size and focus it. This is my code:

```
    var newSpan = "<span  style='font-size:'"+$scope.kys_selected_font+"px' id='idNo'"+$scope.idNo +" >This is ome text</span>";

                             $("#content").append(newSpan);
                              $("#idNo"+ $scope.idNo).focus();
                                $scope.idNo++;
```

where

- $scope.kys_selected_font = FontSize
- $scope.idNo = is a Id number

Comment: var newSpan = "<span  style=font-size:"+101+"px id='idNo'"+109 +" >This is ome text</span>";

Comment: focus a span, could you elaborate?

Comment: when i add new element i want cursor to be on it

Comment: var newSpan = "<span  style=font-size:"+101+"px id=idNo"+109+" >This is ome text</span>";...try this one...

Answer (score 1):

You made some syntax error in defining style inside span, which would come into play when the string newSpan is appended as an element. The **newSpan** code should look like-

```
var newSpan = "<span  style='font-size:" + $scope.kys_selected_font + "px;' id='idNo" + $scope.idNo + "'>This is ome text</span>";
```

You made the same mistake in declaring id, syntax error. Look at the code above. It will fix the focus issue.
Prefer **.css()** method of jquery to add styles to elements, it is much cleaner and less time consuming to handle.